# JS Canvas has varying line width

Tags: javascript, canvas

For some reason, the lines in the left half of this seem thicker than the right side. Can any of you js and canvas gurus help me figure out what the problem is? What can I do to make it so both halves of the tree have equal line widths? http://jsfiddle.net/msm595/ZxVne/18/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way? http://jsfiddle.net/8E9t3/

Basically, I made the `stroke()` occur only at the end.